# JS: Pass items from arrays as parameters for a function

Tags: javascript

for example:

```
function example({array 1 item x}, {array 2 item x})
```

I'd imagine I'll need some sort of for loop that passes each item individually with the equivalent item from both arrays.

actual code:

```
function hide(bool, item) {
  if (bool) {
    document.getElementById(item).classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById(item).classList.remove("show");
    bool = false;
  }
}
```

I need to run this for every `id` I want to hide and show, so I figured I could put the bools list and items list in an array and individually run them together to eliminate unnecessary redundancy.

Comment: Can you add your code. Also add your expected output?

Comment: What is the problem or issue you're facing? What do your arrays look like and what are you trying to do? Is array1 item x somehow linked to array2 item x. Using just `function example(a, b) {}` will do what you want, then when you call `example()` you'll need to pass through your array elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show element using one function call

this will hide or show multiple element by id

```js
function showAndHide(bool, item) {
  if (bool.length !== item.length) throw new Error('bool and item length is different')

  bool.forEach((bool2, index) => {
    if (bool2) {
      document.getElementById(item[index]).classList.add("show");
      document.getElementById(item[index]).classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(item[index]).classList.add("hide");
      document.getElementById(item[index]).classList.remove("show");
    }
  })
}
```